# AWS Target group logical id from ARN for setting TargetGroup dimension in a cloudwatch CDK metric

Tags: java, aws-cdk

According to cloudwatch metrics documentation [1] of ApplicationELB, the TargetGroup 'dimension' should be in the format:

```
Specify the target group as follows: targetgroup/target-group-name/1234567890123456 (the final portion of the target group ARN).
```

How do we get the target group final portion of the ARN, in code time, as the logical id will be resolved deploy time?

The ARN is at my disposal, but I have not managed to get the final portion.
What I have tried:

1. stack.parseArn(...) will not have the logical id part.
2. Getting the logical id from the Construct IApplicationTargetGroup seems not possible.
3. Fn.split(..., ':') doesn't split the arn unfortunately.. (Is that a bug?).

Any ideas on how to resolve the targetgroup/[resourcename]/[logicalid] from the ARN in code time? Or construct this string from 'deploy time' method calls.

Thank You

[1]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your use-case exactly. You can use the `GetAtt` intrinsic function to get the `TargetGroupFullName` attribute from the resource.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-return-values

I think from your question you're using the Java CDK? If so this might be the fella you're looking for - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/core/Fn.html#getAtt-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-